# Pytorch method for conditional use of intermediate layer instead of final cnn layer output. ie: allow nn to learn to use more layers or less

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, control-flow, deep-residual-networks

I'm implementing a residual cnn(modified smaller version of xception) in a low latency environment. I've done a lot of manual tuning to minimize the run time speed of my network (reducing number of filters, removing layers, etc).

But now I want to try allowing my network to make its classification prediction(final fcnn layer) on the residual connection after each residual block.

basic logic-

attempt final prediction with residual connection as input

if this fcnn layer predicts a certain class with a probability > a set threshold:

```
return fcnn output as if it was normal final layer
```

else:

```
do next residual block like normal and try the previous conditional again unless we are already at final block
```

[image: basic example]

My hope is this will allow my network to learn to solve easier problems with less computation while allowing it to still do the additional layers if it is still unsure of the classification.

**So my basic question is**: In pytorch, whats the best way to implement this conditional in a way that allows my nn at run time to decide whether to do more processing or not

Currently Ive tested returning the intermediate x's after the blocks in the forward function, but I dont know how best to setup the conditional to chose which x to return

Also side note: I believe I may end up needing another cnn layer between the residual and fcnn to serve as a function to convert the internal representation for processing to a representation the fcnn understands for classification.

Comment: heres the base version of the xception network im modifying. https://github.com/Cadene/pretrained-models.pytorch/blob/master/pretrainedmodels/models/xception.py

Answer (score 1):

It has already been done and presented in ICLR 2018.

It appears as if in ResNets the first few bottlenecks learn representations (and therefore cannot be skipped) while the remaining bottlenecks refine the features and therefore can be skipped at a moderate loss of accuracy. (*Stanisław Jastrzebski, Devansh Arpit, Nicolas Ballas, Vikas Verma, Tong Che, Yoshua Bengio* [**Residual Connections Encourage Iterative Inference**](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SJa9iHgAZ), ICLR 2018).

This idea was taken to the extreme with *sharing* weights across bottlenecks in *Sam Leroux, Pavlo Molchanov, Pieter Simoens, Bart Dhoedt, Thomas Breuel, Jan Kautz* [**IamNN: Iterative and Adaptive Mobile Neural Network for efficient image classification**](https://openreview.net/forum?id=BkG3_ykDz), ICLR 2018.